# how to write caml query to count item created in each month

Tags: sharepoint-addin, caml-query

I need to write CAML query to count items created in each month.It should give me a count of items created in particular month.

Answer (score 1):

Use `SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime` to create relevant DateTime string.

```
DateTime firstDay = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1);
string firstDayValue = SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(firstDay);
string firstDayValueplus1Month = SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(firstDay.AddMonths(1));
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.Query = "<Where><And><Geq><FieldRef Name='Date' /><Value  Type='DateTime'>" + firstDayValue +
                    "</Value></Geq><Leq><FieldRef Name='Date' /><Value Type='DateTime'>" + firstDayValueplus1Month +
                    "</Value></Leq></And></Where>";
```

Count the number of items returned in this Query.

Example:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(properties.Web.Site.ID))
{
using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(properties.Web.ID))
{ 
SPList list = web.Lists["ListName"];
SPListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(query);
int itemCount = listItems.Count;
}
}
```

Comment: can u explain the above code

Comment: Sure. It first captures first day of current month and then captures first day  of next month. Then finds number of listitems between these two dates which gives items of current month.

Comment: i need  caml to fetch  items in all months

Comment: Correct. So instead of using DateTime.Now.Year, you can pass year and month of your desired timeframe

Comment: how to count each item for a particular month and  how to i set timeframe for all month

Comment: CAML isn't going to give you a count. You are going to need to use what 404 has proposed and then use the .Count method to get the item count of the resulting returned collection.